# Ionic / AngularJS - defer vertical scroll event to parent element

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have content like this:

```
<ion-content delegate-handle="mainScroll">
  <ion-scroll delegate-handle="horizontalScroll" direction="x">
  </ion-scroll>
  <ion-scroll delegate-handle="horizontalScroll" direction="x">
  </ion-scroll>
  <ion-scroll delegate-handle="horizontalScroll" direction="x">
  </ion-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

Basically what I want is multiple horizontal scrollers (ion-scroll) inside a parent container (ion-content) which scrolls vertically.  The trouble is that trying to grab onto the horizontal scroller and drag it vertically doesn't work, so I need to somehow defer that event to the parent.

I see the delegate function:

```
<ion-scroll delegate-handle="horizontalScroll" direction="x" on-scroll="delegateScroll()">
</ion-scroll>

$scope.delegateScroll = function() {
  // what do I do here?
}
```

But I'm not sure how to grab that event and do something useful with it.  Help?

Comment: generally angular directives that fire on DOM events will expose the event via `$event`.  I'd try seeing if that exists first.  Then you should be able to call $event.preventDefault() or something and then pass it up to the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own problem.  It's way more complicated than I thought it would be, but it works.  See the codepen below.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BoGkA

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $ionicScrollDelegate, $timeout) {
  $timeout(function(){
    return false; // <--- comment this to "fix" the problem
    var sv = $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('horizontal').getScrollView();

    var container = sv.__container;

    var originaltouchStart = sv.touchStart;
    var originalmouseDown = sv.mouseDown;
    var originaltouchMove = sv.touchMove;
    var originalmouseMove = sv.mouseMove;

    container.removeEventListener('touchstart', sv.touchStart);
    container.removeEventListener('mousedown', sv.mouseDown);
    document.removeEventListener('touchmove', sv.touchMove);
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', sv.mousemove);


    sv.touchStart = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault = function(){}
      originaltouchStart.apply(sv, [e]);
    }

    sv.touchMove = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault = function(){}
      originaltouchMove.apply(sv, [e]);
    }

    sv.mouseDown = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault = function(){}
      originalmouseDown.apply(sv, [e]);
    }

    sv.mouseMove = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault = function(){}
      originalmouseMove.apply(sv, [e]);
    }

    container.addEventListener("touchstart", sv.touchStart, false);
    container.addEventListener("mousedown", sv.mouseDown, false);
    document.addEventListener("touchmove", sv.touchMove, false);
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", sv.mouseMove, false);
  });
});
```